# Change Default MsTest Unit Test Wizard Template

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mstest, t4

My team is using the unit test wizard, but has found the amount of cruft generated annoying.  Is there anyway to modify this template?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, on several levels:

**Project Template**

You can get rid of the "About Test Projects" and other files using the Options menu in Visual Studio.

Go to Test Tools -> Test Project and unselect the options you don't want.

If that is not enough, you can find the project template in a folder similar to this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Test\1033

Your path may differ slightly if you run on 32-bit Windows or have a different culture, but you should be able to find it.

**Unit Test File Template**

In vanilla Visual Studio, the templates for the unit test can be found in a folder similar to this (from my machine):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033

In this folder there is a file called SimpleUnitTest.zip that contains two files:

- SimpleUnitTest.cs
- SimpleUnitTest.vstemplate

You can edit the SimpleUnitTest.cs file to remove all the code you don't want to have, but you must remember to re-zip the file so that it contains your changes.

However, if you *only* do that, VS may not pick up your changes anytime soon, since it maintains an unzipped cache of templates in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\1033

So you will need to edit the file there as well (or simply copy your changed file there).

As far as I have been able to tell, VS normally uses the templates in ItemTemplateCache, but occasionally reinstates them from ItemTemplates. This seems to happen when updates are applied, but I have yet to identify a consistent pattern, so simply updating in both places is the best way to modify the templates that I have been able to come up with.

Comment: Unfortunately it only works for "Unit Test" item template, but "Unit Test Wizard" use template from somewhere else.

Comment: Regent, do you happen to know where that is? I need to modify that Wizard to use the same cs file. We added some code to the MyClassInitialize and we need it to exist everytime a new test is created. Thanks.