# How can I change the template Visual Studio uses to create MSTest unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mstest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Default MsTest Unit Test Wizard Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468484/change-default-mstest-unit-test-wizard-template)

When I use the unit test wizard from Visual Studio 2010, it generates a new test class that has code like:

```
private TestContext testContextInstance

/// <summary>
///Gets or sets the test context which provides
///information about and functionality for the current test run.
///</summary>
public TestContext TestContext 
{
  get
  {
    return testContextInstance;
  }
  set
  {
    testContextInstance = value;
  }
}

#region Additional test attributes
//a commented chunk of code here
#endregion
```

Since I rarely use `TestContext`s and Test/Class initialization, usually the first this I do is delete this block of text. Is there a way to find and change the template that VS2010 uses, so I don't have to do that anymore?