# Make nUnit as default in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nunit

I have created a Test Project in my solution where other projects too exists, added "nUnit" framework to the Test Project.

On one of the method present in BusinessLayer, right clicked and clicked "Create Unit Test",
It created a Unit Test Method in Test Project, however it takes default Visual Studio Unit Test attributes as mentioned below instead of nUnit attributes ( I need to manually change the attributes to work with nUnit ), How to avoid this or How to make nUnit as default Unit Testing Tool in visual Studio.

```
  [TestMethod()]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Projects\\XXXXX", "/")]
        [UrlToTest("http://localhost:64721/")]
        public void GetSequenceTest()
        {
            int stop = 0; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            int[] expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            int[] actual;
            actual = Helper.GetSequence(stop);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

Instead it should get:

```
[Test]
        public void GetSequenceTest()
        {
            int stop = 0; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            int[] expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            int[] actual;
            actual = Helper.GetSequence(stop);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

Comment: It looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468484/change-default-mstest-unit-test-wizard-template

Comment: No, this doesn't help me.